# What is the purpose of the "Javascript Origins" when creating a Client ID

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

When you create a Google API credential for a web app, you indicate allowed Javascript Origins which is just a list of URIs.  I'm trying to understand what the purpose of these is.

The implication is that any JS code that presents the client ID has to be sourced from the allowed origins to access Google's APIs (such as the Calendar API or Google+ API).  But how does that help?

1. The Client ID is public knowledge and spoofing the origin would be trivial for malicious code.
2. The first thing I do is add "http://localhost:8080" so I can run code from my development environment but of course every computer self identifies as "localhost" so I've effectively negated any security from it.

What is the point of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of origins is so the developer can specify which domains the client can be run from. The spoofing factor is removed because of that. For example, when using Google Drive integration, the google iframe loads and HTTP header:

x-frame-options:ALLOW-FROM https://www.yourorigin.com

That header instructs the browser to only load if it's coming from yourorigin.com. That is the URL specified when creating the client on the Google Developer Console.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is it correct to state then that when I add "http://localhost" to the allowed origins I've basically undermined any security I was otherwise getting from that feature?

Comment: Google is going to give an origin mismatch error if you use localhost when your app is live. The user won't be able to grant it access for the oauth handshake to happen. They could download a copy of your app/site, and then localhost would match the origin you set, so in a way, yes that would enable someone to bypass your origin, but it's cumbersome.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is also used by Google to enable CORS support in their APIs.